# Explain the convexity by looking the hessian matrix of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The hessian matrix of a function is given by,
$$
  H = \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b & c \\[0.3em]
        b & b & 0\\[0.3em]
        c & 0 & c
      \end{bmatrix}
$$

where, $a,b,c>0$.

How do we show that the function given my this matrix is convex or concave?

Comment: @felagund do you have good referance to read about Sylvester’s criterion?

Answer (score 1):

Twice differentiable function is convex on a convex set if and only if its Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite on the interior of the convex set. You can use Sylvester’s criterion to check the positive semidefiniteness:
$$
\begin{cases}
a \ge 0, \\
ab - b^2 \ge 0,  \\
abc - b^2c-c^2b \ge 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Using your conditions $a, b, c > 0$ we get that if $a \ge b + c$ then you function is convex (but not if and only if, Sylvester’s criterion is only sufficient condition but not necessary).

Similarly you can do for concavity.

Comment: do you have good referance to read about Sylvester’s criterion?

Comment: Wiki's article is good.